# Security best practice for calling Lambda from a S3 hosted static website to be used by unauthenticated users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am building a simple website that I am hosting on S3 and distributing through CloudFront. Users will enter some data and click a button to get an output based on their inputs. I have a Lambda that I am calling from the JS hosted on S3 to process the input data and determine the output data. Right now, for testing, I have enabled Lambda function URL without IAM authentication. As I understand, this is a security risk because anyone can view the JS on the client side and get the Lambda function URL and make calls to it.

I have looked at various options suggested on posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175486/where-to-store-api-gateway-credentials-in-aws-serverless-website-served-from-s3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917574/trigger-lambda-from-a-button-in-a-static-website-in-s3). I could use Cognito to handle authentication with or without API gateway. That sounds good. However, I don't necessarily want my users to authenticate themselves. Maybe in the future, but not right now. Unauthenticated users should be able to use the website as well. I understand Cognito provides capability for guest users also and I could use that.

However, I am not sure if there is a point in using Cognito in this case. My objective is to secure the Lambda function and prevent it from being called directly other than through my website. If I use Cognito and enable guest access for unauthenticated users, anyone can do the same (after viewing my JS) and get access to my Lambda. Am I missing something here. What's the security best practice in this scenario where I have to allow unauthenticated users on the website?